# JTS Topology Suite in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, jts

I'm trying to use JTS Topology Suite with ItelliJ (Java) and i'm not able to run even a simple program

I have tried using this POM [file](https://github.com/locationtech/jts/blob/master/USING.md) but when I modified my POM file I have this error:

```
Error:(1, 1) java: package org.locationtech.jts.geom does not exist
```

I have tried even with an empty class to discard other issues:

```
import org.locationtech.jts.geom.*;

public class geo {}
```

How should I include JTS in my project?

Comment: What is the groupId of the jts dependency you are using?

Comment: Where can I see the groupID? I'm new with Java and Maven and still i'm not good with it

Answer (score 0):

I just finally do it with this POM file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>as</groupId>
    <artifactId>a</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.locationtech.jts</groupId>
            <artifactId>jts-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.15.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>locationtech-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.locationtech.org/content/groups/releases</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>jts-snapshots</id>
            <url>https://repo.locationtech.org/content/repositories/jts-snapshots</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```